# Unable to connect to rmq hosted on openshift from my local machine

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to connect to rabbitMQ hosted/installed/deployed on openshift container from my local machine, and i'm facing issues.

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(credentials=credentials, host=settings.RABBIT_MQ_HOST, port=settings.RABBIT_MQ_PORT))
```

here settings.RABBIT_MQ_HOST i have given container hostname got **getaddrinfo failed** error and tried ip of the container pod got **pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError** can some please help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this network connection should succeed? Which documentation are you following?